# using HtmlAgilityPack to locate the text inside a span tag

Tags: c#, xpath

Requirement : Get the value 4.030 by locating the node containing 'Last'

```
<tbody><tr>
<td rowspan="2" class="bg1 W1">
<ul class="UL1">
    <li class="LI1 font12_grey W1">Last</li>
</ul>
<ul class="UL1">
    <li class="LI2 font28 C bold W1"><span class="pos bold">4.030</span></li>
</ul>
```

```csharp
nameNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[text()='Last']/ul/li/span"); 
foreach (HtmlNode x in nameNodes)
    Debug.WriteLine(x.InnerText);
```

I tried many other ways but still not able to get the 4.030

Appreciate if anyone can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
nameNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='UL1']/li/span"); 
 foreach (HtmlNode x in nameNodes)
 Debug.WriteLine(x.InnerText);
```

not tested but give it a try!

Comment: This works, thank you. I think I complicated the case. Previously I kept thinking to locate the "Last" keyword to pin to a specific position to extract the following sibling element.